# ratchet, wss & nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, websocket, ratchet

my current nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain-error.log;

    root /var/www/domain/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

# PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to run 2 secure WebSocket servers (wss://) - one running over 8443 port and the other over 8444.
I tried many configuration suggestions but none of them seems to work (connection timeout).

**UPDATE:**

I want to be able to connect to the WebSocket server like this:

```
conn = new ab.Session('wss://domain:8443',....)
```

Is it possible? or should I change the connection URI?

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of digging, I managed to solve my problem:

**I already tried the settings below from the beginning, but in my case all of my problem was firewall settings.. and yes, it's pretty dumb**

First - the cause of time out problem was the firewall

So, in order to enable your tcp port, use (Centos 7):

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
```

then,

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

great guide: http://ask.xmodulo.com/open-port-firewall-centos-rhel.html

My settings:

```
upstream websocket{
    server 127.0.0.1:8443;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default Upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 default_server ssl http2 ipv6only=on;
        ssl on;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem;

        if ($request_uri ~ "^[^?]*//") {
            rewrite "(.*)" $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/domain-error.log;

        root /var/www/domain/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name domain

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
        location /ws/ {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
            proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
            keepalive_timeout 86400s;
            # prevents 502 bad gateway error
            proxy_buffers 8 32k;
            proxy_buffer_size 64k;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            reset_timedout_connection on;
        }
}
```

Hope it will help others :)